# Visual Studio: export diagram as image?

Tags: visual-studio, diagram

Is there a way in VS to save a diagram designer canvas as an image? (assuming it's larger than the screen, otherwise a screen capture would fit the bill)

In particular, I'm interested in exporting an image of the Config Section Designer:
[image]

... but it looks like it uses the same underlying framework as, say, the Entity Framework designer :
[image]

Comment: have you tried a right click on the diagram to open ContextMenu? the EDMX-Designer has an option to export diagram as image

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work for CSD. I'll try adding a request on Codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a [request](http://csd.codeplex.com/workitem/9936) in the project's tracker. If anybody else feels that this would be useful, vote for it!